# Generally speaking, do I write code that saves memory or code to save processing time for simple objects for smartphone applications?

Tags: java, iphone, android, memory, smartphone

I’m not sure this is the best example, but here goes.  Let’s say I want to draw an object to a canvas in an Android application.  I need to do some math and call a method to return screen size to figure out where to draw it since my app should support multiple screens.  I really only need to do this procedure once, as every time I want the object to be drawn, it is drawn to the same place.  If I only do the procedure once, I have to hold the return values in memory so I can refer back to them later.

Alternatively, I could call the procedure to get these values every time I want to draw the object, so I don’t have to hold any values in memory for the entire lifetime of the activity.

Now I know, not all cases will be the same because I could write a fancy 100,000 line algorithm that just returned an integer value, or go to the opposite extreme, but I’m hoping that there is a common knowledge tradeoff that is generally considered acceptable.

So, what is the correct approach?  Can you elaborate?

Thanks folks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The common knowledge tradeoff I use is, "Do not prematurely optimize."  I build my code, choosing the simplest, clearest implementation I can make at the time.  This is the fastest way to write correctly working code.  Then I test and profile the code.  Only then do I address the areas that need optimization.

If the profiled code uses too much memory, I go back and optimize for space verses time.  Or vice versa if the profiled code runs too slowly.

If I spend too much time pre thinking about how to optimize the code I introduce unnecessary complications and invariably fail to give proper attention to the important optimizations in the final system.

Comment: Ahh, beat me to it, KISS first, then when you step back and see she's fat, try and see where you went wrong.

Comment: I'm basically at the point where I have been implementing things one way and now I have to implement similar functionality.  I figured before I spent the time to do it, I should make sure I wasn't just going to rewrite what I already accomplished.

Comment: @user432209 I know how you feel, but usually, you'll find you'll waste way more time because of trying to predict how the best (premature) optimization for your program is/will be and then debugging the program because of very obscure and tangled code due to premature optimization, then on simply rewriting parts of your app later on to optimize it's resource usage. Development-time-wise, it's best to write your application as natural-looking and clear as possible than to prematurely optimize and fall into debugging and rewriting hell.

Comment: @user432209 (continued) The performance trade-offs compared to the ideal optimizations are unobservable and insignificant as well, so there's little reason to optimize prematurely.

Comment: @user432209 (continued) As for your case, I'd say go for storing the return values in memory, as that's the most natural-seeming implementation to me (because it sounds like it's part of the app/window initialization routine, which should be done only once).

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the type of applications. Do you know the demand-supply curve of economics? go for the marginal cost... At least for smartphones, it not a big deal unless you kill too much memory or processing power to look at your application as awkwardly slow.